# Query Performance: Search by postcode, company name or town

Tags: mysql, sql, database

See the SQL query below - it allow you to search the Shop by Postcode, Company Name or Town (location)... On the frontend website there will be only one search textbox without dropdown search type.

It will only show the result if `shop_options.live` is equal to 1 and depending which day shop is open: `O_Hour.weekday = '5'` (Friday).

If I search by `S_D.postcode` (for example:  `S_D.postcode = 'L14'`) it will then find L14 from `shop_delivery_area` table and then display list of shops from that postcode.

```
SELECT distinct S.*, S.company, S.street, S.town FROM shop as S
    JOIN shop_delivery_area as S_D on S_D.shopID = S.shopID
    JOIN shop_options on shop_options.shopID = S.shopID
    JOIN shop_opening_hours as O_Hour on O_Hour.shopID  = S.shopID
WHERE (S_D.postcode = 'Liverpool'  OR S.company LIKE 'Liverpool' OR S.town LIKE 'Liverpool') 
AND shop_options.live = '1' AND O_Hour.weekday = '5' 
    ORDER BY O_Hour.opentime
```

The query does work but its very slow. Almost a second to get the result. How to improve the performance faster?

Edit: Fixed SQL query.

Comment: How much data do you have? Indexes?

Comment: shop (1,200), shop_delivery_area (5000), shop_options (1200), shop_opening_hours (8000) rows... I have not index them

Comment: Did you already work with EXPLAIN? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html   Indexes might help as well, as you already have ID columns in all tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to keep the predicates i.e.

```
S_D.postcode = 'Liverpool'  OR S.company LIKE 'Liverpool' OR S.town LIKE 'Liverpool'
```

Then consider adding indexes on the same columns. So:

```
ALTER TABLE shop_delivery_area ADD KEY `sda_idx1` (`postcode`);
ALTER TABLE shop ADD KEY `shop_idx1` (`company`);
ALTER TABLE shop ADD KEY `shop_idx2` (`town`);
```

One other point is about fuzzy searching. If you can replace the 'LIKE' with an '=' then you'll see a speed increase. There's not much point using 'LIKE' with no fuzzy searching though i.e. LIKE 'Liverpool'. Use either LIKE '%Liverpool%' or = 'Liverpool'. So either use:

```
    S_D.postcode = 'Liverpool'  OR S.company LIKE '%Liverpool%' OR S.town LIKE '%Liverpool%'
```

or

```
    S_D.postcode = 'Liverpool'  OR S.company = 'Liverpool' OR S.town = 'Liverpool'
```

If you use the latter and create the indexes then your query should run just fine!

Answer (score 0):

The use of [IFNULL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) instead of `OR` may provide substantial performance improvements, depending on your amount of data, indexes, etc.

Answer (score 0):

1. Get rid of conditions for empty strings (`S_D.postcode = ''  OR S.company LIKE ''`)
2. Generally LIKE will slow down your queries a lot, so I'll avoid it whenever it's possible
3. Add indexes on WHERE columns

Comment: But how can I allow customer to search by postcode, company name or town ? There will be only one search textbox.

Comment: You have to prepare the query based on the input of the user inside your application code. If user fills in only the town and other text boxes are empty - query only the town condition. If all text boxes are empty - query without conditions (instead S_D.postcode = ''  OR S.company LIKE '' OR S.town LIKE '')

Comment: I understand what you mean but I want only one search textbox (`WHERE (S_D.postcode = 'Liverpool'  OR S.company LIKE 'Liverpool' OR S.town LIKE 'Liverpool'`)

Comment: I have just seen your edit - having one text box for multiple things - not a good idea IMO. Consider at least adding a drop down list to choose the type of search.